# Integral of fraction for beginners

Tags: integration

I've put this function in Wolfram Alpha

[image]

And as a result I've got the following.

[image]

I know that the derivative of $$log (x+2)- log (2-x) = -4/x^2 - 4$$

But that still doesn't look like the function above. 
Can someone tell me step by step how to get to the solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
-x^3-x^2+4x + 4 = -x^2(x+1) + 4(x+1)
$$
Then we can see that
$$
\frac{x+1}{-x^3-x^2+4x + 4 } = \frac{x+1}{-x^2(x+1) + 4(x+1)} = \frac{1}{4-x^2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have indeed that

$$\frac{x+1}{-x^3-x^2+4x+4}=\frac{x+1}{-x^2(x+1)+4(x+1)}=-\frac{1}{x^2-4}=\frac14 \frac1{x+2}-\frac14 \frac1{x-2}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is an algorithm to handle such integrals: [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Answer (score 2):

$$-x^3 - x^2 + 4x + 4 = -x^2(x+1) +4(x+1) = (x+1)(4-x^2)$$

meaning that

$$\frac{x+1}{-x^2-x^2+4x+4} = \frac{x+1}{(x+1)(-x^2+4)} = \frac{1}{-x^2+4}$$

which is also the derivative you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Use that$$\frac{x+1}{-x^3-x^2+4x-4}=\frac{1}{4(x+2)}-\frac{1}{4(x-2)}$$